# how to pass patch type in patch_namespaced_deployment function in python kubernetes client?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I need help in `patch_namespaced_deployment` function in **python** *kubernetes client*, how i can pass patch type in this function. I want to use `MergePatchType` for patching the deployment.

api_instance.patch_namespaced_deployment(name, namespace, body, pretty=pretty, dry_run=dry_run, field_manager=field_manager, force=force)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I used the golang client for this task with MergePatchType.